# parse JIRA REST API response using php

Tags: php, json, curl, jira-rest-api

I tried several times and several methods to parse long json data in JIRA REST API response. but I couldn't

I want to parse Json using PHP. So I used pure php and curl also but i couldn’t. Please help me to solve this. I'm new in REST API and php-curl

Here is my JIRA REST Response
https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/issue/JRA-9

Here is my sample php-curl code

```
<?php 
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/issue/JRA-9");
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

finally. I solve that.I have to enable CuRL extension first on local server(WAMP or XAMPP) that is my issue

[image: php extensions]